# Tag it submit id not value or label

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

using this plugin
https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it
its very cool by the way.

problem:

```
        <input type="hidden" name="tags" id="mySingleField" value="Apple, Orange" disabled="true">
        Tags:<br>
        <ul id="mytags"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mytags").tagit({
            singleField: true,
            singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField'),
            allowSpaces: true,
            minLength: 2,
            removeConfirmation: true,
            tagSource: function (request, response) {
                //console.log("1");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../City/GetList",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.label + " (" + item.id + ")",
                                value: item.value
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });



</script>
```

When tag it selects the values it adds values to the hidden field in CSV format in value attr. i want it to do ID instead anyone know how to ?

Comment: may I ask why do you want to do it

Comment: i want to pass id not the values back to server

Comment: [Line #238 of the plugin provided](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/js/tag-it.js#L283) is where the value is being set, if that helps.

Comment: question also in https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/issues/130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the tag-it.js file

Comment from line 264

```
// that.createTag(that._cleanedInput());

// The autocomplete doesn't close automatically when TAB is pressed.
// So let's ensure that it closes.
// that.tagInput.autocomplete('close');
```

around line 285

```
var autocompleteOptions = {
    select: function(event, ui) {
        that.createTag(ui.item);
```

Create a new function

```
assignedTagsData: function(){
    // Only to be used when singleField option is not seleted
    var tags = [];
    this.tagList.children('.tagit-choice').each(function() {
        tags.push($(this).data('tag_item_data') );
    });
    return tags;
}

that.createTag(ui.item);
```

Create tag

```
var tag = $('<li></li>')
    .data('tag_item_data',item) //add this line
    .addClass('tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all')
    .addClass(additionalClass)
    .append(label);
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things here.  You can set the delimeter instead of a CSV to anything by setting the parameter as such say to an underscore:

```
$("#mytags").tagit({
  ...
  singleFieldDelimiter: '_',
  ...
```

Then you can modify the tag-it.js file on line 197 to say use the ID attribute.

Change:

```
var tags = node.val().split(this.options.singleFieldDelimiter);
```

To be

```
var tags = node.attr("id").split(this.options.singleFieldDelimiter);
```

So let's say that you modified the hidden field to be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tags" class="mySingleField" id="Apple_Orange_Banana" value="Apple_Orange" disabled="true">
```

You would modify the javascript as such to get the desired output:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mytags").tagit({
            singleField: true,
            singleFieldNode: $('.mySingleField'),
            singleFieldDelimiter: '_',
            allowSpaces: true,
            minLength: 2,
            removeConfirmation: true,
            tagSource: function (request, response) {
                //console.log("1");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../City/GetList",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.label + " (" + item.id + ")",
                                value: item.value
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
   });
```

Comment: if i have item with (id, label, value) does this change select the id from select tag item and set it to value field in Input element or does it select value from item tag selected and add it to input idattr? i want the 1st one

Comment: This will tag the value of the ID and make a tag for each value separated by the underscore.  Is this what you were looking to do?

Comment: what i am looking for is if my tags are (id,lable,values) (1,apple , apple) i want to see <input id="selecttag" value="1,2,3"/> . On the displayed tag i want to see value apple.... currently it does <input id="selecttag" value="apple,orange,pears"/> and displays apple..